# Swift - How Can I handle datas from FIRUserInfo for FB Auth?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook-authentication

I have just started **Firebase's new SDK**.

```
let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) in

let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
```

After that while getting Facebook Informations,

I have encountered a problem, **How Can I handle all of them again?**:

```
 var userData =
                                ["id": FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid as! AnyObject,
                                 // "accessToken": credential as! String,
                                 // "provider": user.provider!,
                                 "displayName": user?.providerData["displayName"],
                                 "email": user.providerData["email"] as! String,
                                 "profileImageURL": user.providerData["profileImageURL"] as! String,
                                 // "token": user.token as String,
                                 "createdAt": utcTimeZoneStr]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a for ... in to retrieve the providerData now.

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
  for profile in user.providerData {
    let providerId = profile.providerId
    let uid = profile.uid;  // Provider-specific UID
    let name = profile.displayName
    let email = profile.email
    let photoUrl = profile.photoURL
  }
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

Comment: Is `profile.uid` always same as `user.uid`? I am wondering the best one to use as key in the Realtime Database for a node like `/users/{uid}/...`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the properties of FirAuth (current user):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_user#properties