# Firebase Provider Data

Tags: xcode, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get a Firebase user's provider information (Email, Facebook, Twitter, etc). When I run `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.providerID` I get and output of `Firebase` even when the user signs up with Twitter. When I run `FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.providerData` I get `[<FIRUserInfoImpl: 0x7a63e7f0>]`. **How do I get an output of `Facebook` or `Twitter`?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - How Can I handle datas from FIRUserInfo for FB Auth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316332/swift-how-can-i-handle-datas-from-firuserinfo-for-fb-auth)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    if let providerData = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.providerData {
        for item in providerData {
            print("\(item.providerID)")
        }
    }
```